# Do you know a good book or study on the philosophical background of the ZFC axioms?

Tags: reference-request, axiom-of-choice, axioms, philosophy

I'm especially interested in how the Axiom of Choice might be derived from nature through philosophy. After studying basic set theory at university, I could convince myself of the ZF axioms being true, as they coincide with the way I personally see nature. This also holds for some weaker versions of choice, such as Countable Choice and DC. However, it is not the case with AC. I'd like to build AC into the way I see nature, to not only use it, but believe it in a way that transcends mathematics.

Comment: Maybe https://www.amazon.co.uk/Defending-Axioms-Philosophical-Foundations-Theory/dp/0199671486/

Comment: By transfinite induction: If $\sf DC_\kappa$ is true, then surely $\sf DC_{\kappa^+}$ is true. Since you believe $\sf DC$, you get choice at least until the first inaccessible cardinal, which means you have a model of ZFC where "standard mathematics lives in". And honestly, if you believe that everything is well-ordered up to the first inaccessible, then either that's everything or you accept large cardinals exist, in which case, by analogous argument to $\omega$ you should be able to convince yourself that the induction goes on.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown  Thanks, this seems to be what I am looking for.